# Прием у кого-л. vs. прием кого-л

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика

> Мухин явился на прием директора точно в назначенный срок.

В чем здесь ошибка?

Из "Словаря грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка" РАН:

> Приём, м.
>
> 3. Пустить кого-н. к себе с какой-н. целью — для беседы, для осмотра и т. п.
>    а) *Кого* — с одушевл. существительным в родительном падеже (субъектом): *Прием **врача** идет с 16 часов; Прием **депутата** состоится в субботу*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Мухин явился на прием директора точно в назначенный срок.
>
> В чем здесь ошибка?

.

Ошибка — в сочетании *"явился **на приём директора**"*.

.

Из *"Словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка"* под ред. Морковкина:

> **На приём** к кому-л. (явиться / прийти / записаться / попасть  …).
>
> **На приёме** у кого-л. (быть …).
>
> **Приём** [кого-л.] начался, продолжается, назначен на какое-л. время, окончен …
>
> *Мухин **явился на приём к директору**  точно в назначенный срок.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: slava, а можно сказать: прием врача начался?

Comment: Я бы так не говорил. Почему Лазуткина (автор словаря, упомянутого Aer) считает такое употребление нормативным -- не знаю. Меня многое  чего в её словаре удивляет.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется.

Answer (score 1):

Мухин явился на прием директора точно в назначенный срок. 
На приём К КОМУ? к директору (д.п.) 
А вот принимать КОГО? посетителя (р.п.)

Когда мы говорим НА приём директора, получается, что этот приём директору принадлежит, это его часть: (ср. лапа медведя, ручка портфеля, дверца шкафа и т.д.)

Таким образом, приём КОГО?, но НА приём К КОМУ?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Мухин явился на прием **к директору** точно в назначенный срок.

1) **Похожий пример:** Как попасть **на прием к депутату**?  **Прием граждан** по личным вопросам и работа с обращениями граждан являются важной и неотъемлемой частью обязанностей каждого депутата.

[Как попасть в Госдуму | kakprosto.ru](http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-25842-kak-popast-na-priem-k-deputatu)

2) **В словаре сочетаемости, как я думаю, напрасно совмещены две формы**: прием врача (действие субъекта) и прием пациента (объект действия). На слух  первая форма совершенно не воспринимается, да и в текстах, кажется,  не встречается.

Comment: Так а почему *к директору*? Какое правило? В каком словаре или ином лингвистическом источнике фиксируется норма?

Comment: >> *На слух первая форма [прием врача] совершенно не воспринимается, да и в текстах, кажется, не встречается* **Прием врача-офтальмолога - с 10 часов утра по рабочим дням.**

Comment: Да, табличка "прием врача" нормально читается,  а вот предложения с такой формой не очень, например:  "В рамках перевода Интернет-записи на прием к врачу в режим доступности...".  Наверное, в сочетаниях эта форма становится двусмысленной: непонятно, кто кого принимает. Вот предложение: Как попасть на приём посла? Что это за мероприятие: посол принимает или посла принимают?

Answer (score -1):

«Явился на приём директора». Словарь прав и, как оказалось, не один. Но мы потому настороженно относимся к этой конструкции, что чаще слышим и употребляем ту, в которой *директор* управляется глаголом: ***явился к директору*** на приём.

Меняя слова местами (явился на приём к директору) или совсем отбрасывая глагол, мы пытаемся рассматривать фразу в условиях перекладывания функцию управления на другое слово — приём, что неверно: отдельной связки «*на приём* (явился к кому?) *к директору*» **без учёта глагола** (видимого или не видимого) быть не может.

Насчёт назначенного *срока*: как-никак это всё-таки период или его начало и конец. Поскольку речь здесь не идёт о каком-то процессе, лучше было б употребить слово *час* или *время*: в назначенный час, в назначенное время.

Comment: shampar, извините, но в словаре не написано НА приём, там есть ПРОСТО  слово "приём" - большая разница!

Comment: И это то, в чём прав словарь: приём (кого, чей?) врача.

Comment: На то он  и словарь

Comment: Из Словаря под ред. Морковкина, который цитирует slava1947, тоже есть «Приём (кого-л.) начался, продолжается, назначен...». На то они и словари!